# Can't open new Activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

This is my code for first page and when I want to start an Activity I have this error:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.example.loginpage.contact,java.lang.Class)'

```
public class contact extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
Context context;
contact (Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        if (result.equals("Wrong email or password.")) {

        } else
        {
            context.startActivity( new Intent(contact.this,mainpage.class));
        }
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

I want open this activity:

```
public class mainpage extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("Username");
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
        tv.setText(username);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to start a new `Activity` from outside of a `Context`. When you say `contact.this` in the line:

`startActivity( new Intent(contact.this,mainpage.class));`

you are referring to an `AsyncTask` as that's what `contact` extends. You should pass in a `Context` there instead. You can do that by passing `Context` into your class `contact` constructor.

Once you have `Context` passed into the `contact` you replace `contact.this` with:

`context.startActivity(new Intent(context, mainpage.class));`

Comment: I have just seen your edit. You need to pass `Context` into the constructor.

Comment: I don't understand how to use it here

Comment: See the other answer, that's what you need to do. From your `Activity` when you create `contact` you initialise it as `contact myContact = new contact(this)`

Comment: how to use it with Activity

Comment: now is not give error but when I press the button program stopped

Answer (score 0):

```
public class contact extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;

    contact(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    //yout other staff

}
```

then use startActivity( new Intent(context,packagename.mainpage.class));